# Ways to monitor Workling instances in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, workling, starling-server

I'm currently using Workling with Starling on a rails app. Although I like Workling, I find it kinda hard to monitor.

To make matters worse, I have a couple of Workling instances. Workling is running with the :multiple set to 'true' (inside workling_client).

I can see the pid for each instance and such, but I want to know if they're actually doing some work, and find out if I need more (or even less) instances running.

Do you guys have any suggestions of tools, hacks or anything that could help me on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I monitor Workling with monit. It gives you CPU% at any given point in time. If you want to have a look how much load they have had over time then you could use Munin instead as I believe it can give you some graphs via some plugins to it that can tell you a number of things about what you are monitoring. Sorry I can't be more specific as I haven't used Munin.